# Check a Checkbox if it is not checked in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, testing, xpath, automation

I do have the Below Page Source:

```
1. <li_ngcontent-shv-c123 mat-menu-item role="presentation" class="mat-focus-indicator dropdown-item mat-menu-item ng-star-inserted" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false">
2. <mat-checkbox_ngcontent-shv-c123 class= "mat-checkbox example-margin mat-accent _mat-animation-noopable" id="53oo32be-6855-4yt4-965d-y71078b642">
3. <label class="mat-checkbox-layout" for="53oo32be-6855-4yt4-965d-y71078b642-input"> 
4. <div class="mat-checkbox-inner-container">.
5. <input type="checkbox" class="mat-checkbox-input cdk-visually-hidden" id="53oo32be-6855-4yt4-965d-y71078b642-input" tabindex="0" value="53oo32be-6855-4yt4-965d-y71078b642" name="Item List" aria-checked="true"> 
6. <div matripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-checkbox-ripple mat-focus-indicator">
7.  <div class="mat-ripple-element mat-checkbox-persistent-ripple">
8. </div>
9. </div>
10. <div class="mat-checkbox-frame">
11. </div>
12. <div class="mat-checkbox-background">
13. <svg version="1.1" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 31 31" xml:space="preserve" class="mat-checkbox-checkmark">
14.  <path fill="none" stroke="white" d="M2.1,89.5 9,78.6 3.3,77.1" class="mat-checkbox-checkmark-path">
15. </Path>
16. </svg><div class="mat-checkbox-mixedmark">
17. </div>
18. </div>
19. </div>
20. <span class="mat-checkbox-label">
21. <span style="display none;">&nbsp;</span>XYZ Element</span>
22. </label> 
23. </mat-checkbox><div matripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-menu-ripple">
24. </div>
25. </li>
```

In this **Item List** (Line 5) is an Drop Down List having finite number of elements with checkboxes.
What I need to check is for element **XYZ Element** (Line21) in the drop down list and check the checkbox with it if and only if the checkbox is unchecked.

If the checkbox is already checked leave it as such.

I tried with the below code:

```
test= "//span[contains(text(),'XYZ Element')]"

try:

driver.finde_element_by_xpath(test).is_selected()
pass

except:
driver.find_element_by_xpath(test).click()
```

The above code is not yielding the require result.

Is there any alternative way to do this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `find_elements` to see if there's anything in the list, if it is there you can click or check for click like below  :

**code :**

```
try:
    if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'XYZ Element')]/../descendant::input")) > 0 :
        print("Element is present")
        if driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'XYZ Element')]/../descendant::input").is_selected():
            print("it's already selected")
        else:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'XYZ Element')]/../descendant::input").click()
    else:
        print("Element is not present at all")
except:
    print("Check out the code again")
    pass
```

**Update 1 :**

to make `xyz element` variable  :

```
some_str = "XYZ Element"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//span[contains(text(),'{some_str}')]")
```

Comment: I have updated the code again with few checks points, let me know if that works

Comment: Thank you so much.... i made a small change to the 1st code you put and it works great
i hade change in the else part

Comment: in the else part 
`test= "//span[contains(text(),'XYZ Element')]"`
`else:`
`driver.find_element_by_xpath(test).click()`
i put this

Comment: Hi `test= "//span[contains(text(),'XYZ Element')]"` is there a way to make the ***XYZ Element*** as a variable?? i need a variale to be working in the test.
is there any specific syntax?

Comment: I have updated the code above in update 1 section.